# posting data into database-web sql chrome extension

Tags: html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, local-storage

I was planning on saving posts from my servers to my extension. Does Chrome has an unlimited storage web sql example for this?

Thanks.

Comment: You're asking about "database-web sql", "web sql" and "Local Storage". Which of the methods do you mean? [*Deprecated* WebSQL](http://www.w3.org/TR/webdatabase/), [IndexedDB](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/IndexedDB/) or [localStorage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/local-storage)?

Comment: thank you for the clarification. i guess i am interested in indexeddb and client side unlimited storage by chrome. i am planning to post data to my node.js server and save it on my computer through the browser as well. i believe this is possible with unlimited storage by chrome. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read [Using IndexedDB](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/IndexedDB/Using_IndexedDB) and [Basic concepts behind IndexedDB](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/IndexedDB/Basic_Concepts_Behind_IndexedDB) on MDN to learn more about IndexedDB.

By default, Chrome has a quota limit of 5MB. To unlock unlimited storage, you have to add the [`"unlimitedStorage"` permission](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/manifest.html#permissions) to your manifest file.

Comment: sorry i am posting again before reading but does indexedDB have that 5mb quota limit as well? will i have to read about html5 quota api as well? or will unlimited storage solve this limit for me? thanks.

Comment: @LeTruffle Have you read past the first line of my answer? Citation from Google Extension's documentation: "Provides an unlimited quota for storing HTML5 client-side data, **such as databases** and local storage files. **Without this permission, the extension is limited to 5 MB of local storage**."